# On convergent sequences

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

Suppose that i have and open and surjective map between two metric spaces $\pi\colon X\to Y,$ and a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that its image by $\pi$ converges.

Is it true that $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges, if not under which condition it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I claim that if $\pi$ is injective we get the result**

Let $y\in Y$ be (a) limit of $\pi(x_n)$. Let $x=\pi^{-1}(y)$.

Let $U\subset X$ be an open neighborhood of $x$.

$\pi$ is open, and therefore $\pi(U)$ is a open neighborhood of $y$, so there is $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for every $n>N$ we have $\pi(x_n)\in \pi(U)$ so $x_n\in U$ for all $n>N$ as desiered.

**the claim is not generally correct the way you claimed.**

Comment: Thanks, in this case $\pi$ would be a homemorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Take $X=\mathbb{R},\, Y=\{0\}$ and $x_{n}=n$ . $\pi$ defined by
$\pi(x)=0$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Then $\pi$ is open and surjective
but $x_{n}$ is not convergent while $\pi(x_{n})\equiv0$ is